# How do I pass Postgres function param into a JSON query?

Tags: json, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamicJsonValue(varchar(64)) RETURNS VOID AS
'UPDATE "table" SET "field" = ''value''
 WHERE "json_field" @> ''{"key": $1}'';'
 LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```

I can't get my function param to insert in the query like this.

Answer (score 2):

Not even the quotes match in your statement...

Besides, it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamicJsonValue(varchar(64)) RETURNS void AS
$$UPDATE "table" SET "field" = 'value'
   WHERE "json_field"
         @> CAST ('{"key": "' || replace($1, '"', '') || '" }' AS jsonb)$$
LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Comment: `to_json()` is perfectly safe to escape string literals when composing `json[b]` manually (and it is available from 9.3+). `to_jsonb()` and `json_build_object()` is available where `jsonb` introduced (9.4+).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamicJsonValue(varchar(64)) RETURNS VOID AS
'UPDATE "table" SET "field" = ''value''
 WHERE "json_field" @> jsonb_build_object(''field'', $1);'
 LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```